# I have a function that process a list of floats, and returns a list of floats - how do I find arguments for it that return a list of 0s?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

This probably involves calculus, but I don't remember how to do calculus.

I do know python, but I don't know how to do math in python either.

That's why I'm here.

I have a function that does something like this (**EDIT**: a more representative logic):

```
other_lst  = [1.,2.,3.,4.,5.] # A list of 5 floats from elsewhere
target_lst = [10,20,30,40,50] # A list of 5 ints from elsewhere

def get_result(   a_lst, an_other_lst, a_target_lst ):
    zipped = zip( a_lst, an_other_lst )    # no global(s), a pure call-signature

    _l = [ (x*y) / sum( [ x*y for x,y in zipped ] ) for x,y in zipped ]

    return [ i-j for i,j in zip( _l, a_target_lst ) ]
```

I want to find some non-trivial `lst`, such that
`get_result( lst, other_lst, target_lst ) == [0,0,0,0,0]`.

**EDIT**: or even all values of `lst` such that `get_result(lst) == [0,0,0,0,0]`. This isn't necessary, but it'd be nice if this were possible.

How do I go about doing that?

My original approach was just iterating through some values to approximate an answer, but it's not quite giving me what I want.

Ignore the arithmetic inside the function logic - they're just placeholders for other logic.

Comment: get_result returns a list, not a number. Do you want all the values to be 0?

Comment: Yes, I want [0,0,0,0,0] - I'll edit the question

Comment: `get_result([0,0,0,0,0])` returns `[0,0,0,0,0]`

Comment: The follow on to this is is this iterative?, i.e. the a used to assign to c, is that the same as the a that's passed in or the updated a?

Comment: Thanks @fferri, what if I want all `lst` such that get_result(lst) == [0]*5

@Snark - Yes. In reality I just wanted to demonstrate that the list members are not being evaluated independently.

Comment: You've just switched from "finding _some_ `lst`" to finding "all", which is a vastly different, and harder, question.  Which is it?

Comment: *some* non-trivial solution would suffice. If it's possible to find *all* non-trivial solutions, all the better. *some* would answer my question fine, though.

Comment: depending on your function (whether it is linear, convex, or none of that) it greatly changes *how* and **if** a solution can be found. it is not possible to answer without knowing that.

Comment: The function logic is still arithmetic on floats like the example, is that not enough? The actual core logic looks like: [x+y/sum([x*y for x,y in zip(lst, other_lst)]) for x,y in zip(lst, other_lst)], and other_lst is also a list of floats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *How do I go about doing that?*

Using **`scipy`**, why not wrapping your **`get_result( aLIST )`** into a **`penalty_fun()`**, which then could be operated inside `scipy.optimize.fmin*` suite of solvers?

```
def penalty_fun( x, other_param, yet_another_param ):
    aResultLIST = get_result( x.tolist(), other_param, yet_another_param )
    return sum( [ item**2 for item in aResultLIST )
```

where the minimiser search of the solver uses a vector **`x[:]`** `~ ( a, b, c, d, e )` bearing some initial or random values :

```
fmin_l_bfgs_b( func    = penalty_fun,
               x0      = x,
               args    = [ other_lst, target_lst ],
               iprint  = 5,
               pgtol   = 1E-8,    
               factr   = 1E+9,    
               maxiter = 1E+8,    
               maxfun  = 1E+8     
               )
```

Given the inner tricks inside **`get_result()`** are not too wild, this naive-force may solve, potentially with many initial starting points in `x[:]` to serve your wish as a ready to use solution.

---

The logic, sketched above before edit(s),

```
def get_result(lst):
    # lst is always a list of 5 floats
    a, b, c, d, e = lst

    # logic goes here
    a = a+b
    b = b-c
    c = min(a,b,c)
    d = a*e
    e = d+b

    return [a, b, c, d, e]
```

yields infinitely many solutions:

```
a_OUT = 0 =      a_IN + b_IN                     ->     lin b_IN == -a_IN
b_OUT = 0 =             b_IN - c_IN              ->     lin b_IN ==         c_IN
c_OUT = 0 = min( a_IN,  b_IN,  c_IN )            :: non-lin                                       == min( a_IN, -a_IN, -a_IN ) == abs( a_IN ) == 0
d_OUT = 0 =      a_IN *                    e_IN  :: non-lin      OR( a_IN == 0         e_IN == 0 )
e_OUT = 0 =             b_IN +       d_IN        ::     lin b_IN ==             -d_IN
```

for input:
  `a == 0, b == 0, c == 0, d == 0, e == < -INF, +INF >`

Comment: Thank you! I had to add `approx_grad=True` as an argument to the function call for `fmin_l_bfgs_b()` to avoid crashing on py2.7, but that got me exactly the numbers I wanted! Thank you.

Comment: Sure, man, I forgot to add this part back, as copied a SLOC / code from a gradient auto-generating use-case, where approximate evaluations were not needed :o)

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't involve calculus per se, it would generally involve algebra. But since you're denying us the ability to examine whatever equations you're using, so I'm going to suggest you use [Newton's Root-finding algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) to zero in on terms one at a time as a start.

Edit : Okay, it involves differential calculus, but that's not TERRIBLY hard, and it's fixed for any static set of functions you want in a,b,c,d,e.

Comment: Ok, I updated the question to make it look more like the actual logic